# python valueerror: too many values to unpack using numpy

Tags: python, excel, numpy, python-2.x

I am trying to extract information from a excel file into python, but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\viral\Desktop\python\test.py", line 5, in main
    date, time, temp = np.loadtxt('temperatures.csv', delimiter = ',', unpack = True, dtype = 'str')
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

code:

```
import numpy as np

def main():

    date, time, temp = np.loadtxt('temperature.csv', delimiter = ',', unpack = True, dtype = 'str')

    import itertools
    groups = itertools.groupby(zip(date, temp), lambda dv:dv[0])
    list_of_lists = [[d] + [v[1] for v in values] for d, values in groups]
    list_of_lists = list_of_lists[:len(list_of_lists)-1]
    x = 0 
    while (x < len(list_of_lists)):
        list_of_lists[x] = [float(i) for i in list_of_lists[x]]
        print list_of_lists[x]
        x += 1
    print len(list_of_lists)
```

excel file looks like this. it is in csv format:

[image]

please help debug

raw data from csv file:

```
20130102        9:30:00 AM      34.75
20130102        9:31:00 AM      34.66
20130102        9:32:00 AM      34.6
20130102        9:33:00 AM      34.6
20130102        9:34:00 AM      34.61
20130102        9:35:00 AM      34.65
20130102        9:36:00 AM      34.65
```

it goes on for 65,208 rows

Comment: You're sure you've got the correct delimiter? Can you show us the raw data from the csv? Edit this information to the question.

Comment: Use the debugger or a print to see the return value of `np.loadtxt`

Comment: Post the exact text content of the csv.

Comment: show the output of `print(repr(open('temperature.csv', 'rb').read(100)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out. There are too many rows to unpack. when I separated the csv file into 2 files with ~30k rows each, it worked